# I can't figure EtherPad out

Tags: web, etherpad

I feel like this is probably a pretty dumb question, but I am just completely lost. I have seen (and tried) about ten different ways to install EtherPad on my system, but absolutely nothing on how to actually incorporate it into my web page. One page seemed like it was telling me to open up "http://localhost:3306/" (or something along those lines; the port number is probably wrong) in my browser, but when I did that it tried to "download" a .bin file, which is obviously not what I want.

I've tried looking at the source code of a few pages that use EtherPad, but that didn't help much, either. I honestly couldn't even find anything relating to EtherPad in there. I don't know. I'm just lost.

I feel like I am missing something really major that shouldn't be this hard to figure out. If anyone could point me to a solid tutorial or give me a concise explanation of how it works, I would be immensely grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what way do you want to integrate etherpad? The most common method is to have an  that contains a single etherpad page.

If you want to have the full etherpad functionality then you should look for the templates/ folder to customize etherpad itself.

For more info, search 'integrate' on the official maillist; https://groups.google.com/group/etherpad-open-source-discuss/search?group=etherpad-open-source-discuss&q=integrate&qt_g=Search+this+group

Or if you need practical help with your specific project you might need to pay; John McLear http://mclear.co.uk/ knows this stuff well.